# Terraform circular dependency between security groups

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a setup: ALB in front of ECS. I have a module of ecs and one for alb:
The egress rule of the ALB of `alb_sg`:

```
  egress {
    description     = "Traffic from ALB to ECS"
    from_port       = 80
    to_port         = 80
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [var.ecs_sg] //comes from output from ecs stack
  }
```

Now in ECS I have something like this for its security group (`ecs_sg`)

```
  ingress {
    description = "Allow ALB to ECS"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    security_groups = [var.alb_sg] //comes from output from alb stack
  }
```

Now I have some error:

```
│ Error: Cycle: module.ecs.var.alb_sg (expand), module.ecs.aws_security_group.ecs_sg, module.ecs.output.ecs_sg (expand), module.alb.var.ecs_sg (expand), module.alb.aws_security_group.alb_sg, module.alb.output.alb_sg (expand)
```

How can this be solved? Thanks

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to create the SGs and SG rules separately. You can define the SG rules by using the [`aws_security_group_rule`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group_rule) resource.

Comment: The above is perfect, just adding an example on how to do it. https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/state/troubleshooting-workflow#correct-a-cycle-error