# Applying Terraform aws_security_group_rule on existing security group not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a cloud infrastructure created using Terraform. Due to a cyclic dependency issue with two security groups referring to each other ([Terraform circular dependency between security groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67927921/terraform-circular-dependency-between-security-groups)) , I tried defining a `aws_security_group_rule` for the ingress rules. The error disappeared and Terraform completed execution.

However, I found out that the group rule is only applied correctly whenever the security group in question does not exist yet. When it already exists, Terraform cannot seem to update it. Is there something that can be done to resolve this apart from recreating the resources which really goes against the principle of using Terraform?

See below the code

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "apix_to_apiy_rule" {
  type              = "ingress"
  from_port         = 8080
  to_port           = 8080
  protocol          = "tcp"
  security_group_id = "xxxx"
  source_security_group_id = "xxxx"
}

resource "aws_security_group" "xxxx" {...}
```

Note: Group ID values are just examples.

Comment: " is only applied correctly whenever the security group in question does not exist yet." - what does it even mean? You can't apply any rule to something that does not exist. Your question is unclear and lacks details.

Comment: I'm sorry if it's unclear but in the context of TF, it's either the resource is created or updated. The existing security group in this case should be updated through the `aws_security_group` resource but it's not. However, if the security group does not exist yet and thus needs to be created, it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to modify existing SG using TF, you have to first [import](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import) into TF. Only then you will be able use `aws_security_group.xxxx` resource to manage it.

Alternatively, just use `aws_security_group_rule.apix_to_apiy_rule`, and specify the id of the group through input variable to the template or the [aws_security_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/security_group) data source in:

`source_security_group_id = "<id-of-sg>"`

Comment: Okay it turns out that there's something else going on. Sometimes it gets applied, sometimes not. I'll try to figure it out. At least I'm sure now that it's not how the resources (security_group and security_group_rule) are defined or managed.

Answer (score 0):

If the rule already exists and not managed by Terraform, Terraform cannot update it. This is expected behavior for any resources.

If the rule was created by Terraform, it should be able to detect changes and update it.

Comment: It was created by Terraform and you're right, it should be able to detect changes and update it. At first, I thought there was a mistake in the Terraform script but running it from scratch leads to the expected rules being applied in the security group.